# Find If Record Exists From SQL Query Results In Rest of Data

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, qsqlquery

I have a list of our customers and want to find out if those customers came back and purchased without going through a Google Ads click as we store the GCLID for each sale.

For example, if a customer clicked on an ad and purchased in October, did they come back to the site directly and buy, therefore there would be no GCLID value in that column.

Here is the SQL query I am running to total the times customers came back and purchased, but also want to have a way to track by phone number if they are in the database but without the GCLID value.

```
SELECT Phone, COUNT(Phone) as phones, FROM `customer-data.customer_data.all`  WHERE LENGTH(Gclid) > 55 AND Time BETWEEN "2022-01-01 00:00:00" and "2023-01-01 00:00:00" GROUP BY Phone HAVING COUNT(Phone) > 0 ORDER BY phones DESC
```

Comment: Please add sample data for your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to find all the customers who bought twice or more times and they don't have a GCLID value.

```
WITH duplicates AS (
    SELECT Phone, COUNT(Phone) as phones
    FROM `customer-data.customer_data.all`
    WHERE LENGTH(Gclid) = 0 
    AND Time BETWEEN "2022-01-01 00:00:00" and "2023-01-01 00:00:00"
    GROUP BY Phone
    HAVING COUNT(Phone) > 1
```

)

Then you can JOIN the above subquery with your original query using the phone column.

```
SELECT Phone, COUNT(Phone) as phones
FROM `customer-data.customer_data.all`
WHERE (LENGTH(Gclid) > 55 OR Phone IN (SELECT Phone FROM duplicates))
AND Time BETWEEN "2022-01-01 00:00:00" and "2023-01-01 00:00:00"
GROUP BY Phone
HAVING COUNT(Phone) > 0
ORDER BY phones DESC
```

This query will return customers who have a GCLID value that's longer than 55 characters and also those customers who came back and purchased without a GCLID value.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

However we have multiple sources where traffic can come from and when I run that I get a lot of records that aren't valid.

Maybe to explain another way, I wanted to see if there were any users in the database that have a GCLID value AND those same users (by phone number) came through other means to buy again. The first record would not have to have the GCLID, but at some point they may have come in through Google Ads click and later may have purchased from a direct link or through another means

Comment: Got it, updated. Please take a look now and let me know :)